# Mongodb query modulo with dynamic field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with entries as

```
{_id" : ObjectId("52ff99402cfff2733d826bfe"),"f" : 60}
```

I want to make a query where the "f" field will be incremented with a random value
and passed on modulo operator - something like

```
db.col.find( { f + RANDOM  : { $mod : [100,0] } })
```

This obviously is not working since the filter has to be done on a field name for collection.
How can it be done ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$where`:

```
db.col.find( { $where: "(this.f + RANDOM) % 100 == 0" } )
```

or:

```
db.col.find( function() { return ((this.f + RANDOM) % 100 == 0 ) } );
```

But this solution have some constraints, you could read about it there: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: i'm aware about the eval capabilities but like you mention there are some constraints ... like the eval for each record of the function/code. thanks!